# How to update array in immutable way

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux, immutability

Truble! Help please. I will be so appreciate!

In this object I should update in immutable way only comments array (all of that just a mock data, doesn`t matter):

```
const initialState = {
  news: [
    {
      id: 1,
      text: 'Hello!',
      createdBy: '',
      comments: [{ id: 0, author: 0, commentText: 0 }]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      text: 'TEST',
      createdBy: '',
      comments: [{ id: 11, author: 11, commentText: 11 }, { id: 12, author: 12, commentText: 12 }]
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      text: 'TEXT:)',
      createdBy: '',
      comments: []
    }
  ]
}
```

And it is realy hard... I`ve tried a lot of variants, but it was unsuccessful...(

My reducer:

```
const newsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.ADD_COMMENT:
      const { id, author, commentText, newsItemId } = action.payload;
      // which element to update
      const index = state.news.findIndex(item => item.id === newsItemId);
      return {
        ...state,
        news: [
          ...state.news
          [index] = {
            ...state.news[index],
            comments: state.news[index].comments.concat({ id, author, commentText })
          }
        ]
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Will be grateful for any advice

Comment: At a glance, that doesn't appear to be mutating anything - do you have any information on where exactly the mutation is happening?

Comment: @CertainPerformance, this is react/redux app. Averything should be changed immutably :) But I want to push a new comment to a comments array

Comment: @CertainPerformance as I understand, I cannont just do it like this: state.news[index].comments.concat({ id, author, commentText })... The whole returned state should be immutable

Answer (score 1):

Spread syntax is one way to solve this, another way is using lenses, which can be found in libraries like [Ramda](http://Ramda).

Lenses let you 'zoom' into a specific part of a data structure and update a value, returning a new version of the whole data structure.

```
const R = require('ramda')
const a = {a:'foo', b:[1, 2, 3]}
const b = R.over(R.lensPath(['b']), nums => nums.concat(4), a)
console.log(b) //-> {a:'foo', b:[1, 2, 3, 4]}
```

Using lenses your reducer could be expressed as:

```
const R = require('ramda')
const newsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.ADD_COMMENT:
      const { id, author, commentText, newsItemId } = action.payload
      const i = state.news.findIndex(item => item.id === newsItemId)
      return R.over(
        R.lensPath(['news', i, 'comments']),
        comments => comments.concat({ id, author, commentText }),
        state
      )
      default:
        return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank u so much, but I want to do it without additional libraries. Only vanilla JS (ES6)